# Flipping an image in kineticJS?

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs

I have an image in my code, as defined here

```
    var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function(){
    imageF = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        scale: (100,100),
        image: imageObj,
        name: "fluffy",
    });
    layer.add(imageF);  
    stage.add(layer);
    stage.start();
    }
imageObj.src = "Flutter_Fluffy_100.png";
```

And I would like to be able to have it flip (horizontally) at certain times in the running.  I tried to change the image source to a pre-flipped one, but that caused, well, a lot of problems with the image duplicating, resetting position and lots of stuff.  Is there a method to flip an image that is created and used this way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
//imageF.scale.y =-1;
imageF.scale.x =-1;
```

It's demonstrated here:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-scale-animation-tutorial/

It's pretty much the same with an image:
http://randompast.github.io/randomtests/kineticjs/FlipImage-Demo.html

edit: fixed link

Comment: just to avoid confusion, I'd like to mention that the KineticJS API has changed a bit since this answer was posted.  You can set the horizontal scale like this: imageF.setScale({x:-1});